# Find all pairs$(a,b)$ of real numbers such that $(a+bi)^5=b+ai$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Find all pairs$(a,b)$ of real numbers such that $(a+bi)^5=b+ai$

My Attempt,

If we let $a+bi=r(\cos\theta+ i \sin\theta)$.
Then how should I move on.  Should I have to do 
$(a+bi)^5=[r(\cos\theta +i \sin\theta)]^5$.

Please help. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$z = a+bi\\ \bar z = a-bi\\ i\bar z = b + ai\\
z^5 = i \bar z\\
z = 0 \text { or}\\
z^6 = i\\
z^6 = e^{(2n + \frac 1{2})i}\\ 
z = e^{\frac {(4n+1)\pi}{12}i}$

Update
$z = 0$ or

$z^6 = i$

De Moivre's theoem:

if $z = r(\cos \theta + i \sin\theta)$
then $z^n = r^n(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)^n =r^n(\cos n\theta + i \sin n\theta)$

It also means that 
$z^{\frac 1n} = r^{\frac 1n}(\cos \theta + i \sin \theta)^{\frac 1n} =r^{\frac 1n}(\cos {\frac 1n}\theta + i \sin {\frac 1n}\theta)$

so here we have

$z^6 = i = (\cos (\frac \pi 2 + 2n\pi) + i \sin(\frac \pi 2 + 2n\pi))$

$z = $$(\cos (\frac \pi 2 + 2n\pi) + i \sin(\frac \pi 2 + 2n\pi))^{\frac 16}\\
(\cos (\frac \pi {12} + \frac {n\pi}{3}) + i \sin(\frac \pi {12} + \frac {n\pi}{3}))$

There are 6 solutions + the trivial solution.

Comment: @@Doug M, I know the Euler's identity, $$e^{ix}=cosx+isinx$$

and

$$i=e^{\frac {\pi}{2}}i$$. 

Could you please explain me the solution with this.

Comment: $i = e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}, 1 = e^{2\pi i}, i = e^{(\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi) i}$ gives us a more general solution... i.e. will give us 6 solutions, instead of just the one if we stuck with the slightly more simple $i = e^{\frac{\pi}{2}i}$  So, $z^6 = e^{(\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi) i}$  Now, take the 6th root of each side.  $z = e^{(\frac{\pi}{12}+\frac {n\pi}{3}) i} = e^{\frac{(4n+1)\pi}{12} i} = \cos (\frac{(4n+1)\pi}{12}) + i\sin (\frac{(4n+1)\pi}{12})$

Comment: @@Doug M, how is $i = e^{(\frac{\pi}{2}+2n\pi) i}$ ?

Comment: @@@Doug M, what do I substitute in place of $n$?